# как поместить цикл внутри цикла в custom field suite

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

```
<?php
$fields = CFS()->get('slider-docs');
if (!empty($fields)):
    foreach ($fields as $img) {
        ?>
        <div class="slider__item filter">
                    
                        <img src="<? echo $img['slider-docs-picture']; ?>" alt="s">
                        <div class="slider-img-bg">
                            <p class="slider-img-bg-text">
<!--                                 Свидетельство об оценке<br> состояния измерений<br>  лаборатории -->
                                <? echo $img['name-docs']; ?>
                            </p>
    
                            <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary slider-img-bg-link" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal1">
                                Нажмите, чтобы посмотреть
                            </a>

                            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                            <?php
                            $images = $field['lider-docs-popup'];
                        foreach ($images as $imgs) {
                        ?>
                        <!-- Modal -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal1" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-                                      hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">

                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                    <div class="slider-popup slider-popup-1">
                                        <div class="slider-popup-item slider-popup-1-item">
                                            <img src="<? echo $imgs['slider-docs-popup-picture']; ?>" alt="docs">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php }; ?>
                            
                            
                            
                            
                        </div>
                </div>
                
                        

        <?php
    };
endif; ?>
```

slick slider вывел циклом custom field suite. при нажати по ссылке по id открывается модальное окно со слайдером. картинки вывелись, но модальное окно не показывается. В чем ошибка? Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю в html не может быть много объектов с одинаковым id.

В вашем случае цикл создаёт ряд модальных окон с id="#exampleModal1"

Могу предположить что проблема именно в этом

Comment: А можно тогда как то переделать модальное окно, что бы без id работало

Comment: С кодом, тогда все хорошо?

Comment: Ну вообще неправильно делать больше одного модального окна)

По нажатию кнопки должен исполняться JS код, который перед открытием окна меняет данные в нем на те, которые содержаться в самом блоке.

В вашем случае вообще все непонятно, у вас 1 кнопка в первом цикле, которая вызывает N модальных окон во втором цикле. Тогда уж по логике должно быть N кнопок для N модальных окон

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
                $loop = CFS()->get('portfolio-tehn');
                foreach ($loop as $index => $row) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="portfolio-box portfolio-box-1" style="background-image: linear-gradient(
                        360deg
                        , rgba(2, 39, 79, 0.95) 4.32%, rgba(2, 39, 79, 0) 40.91%), url(<?= $row['picture-portfolio'] ?>);">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-content">

                            
                            
                            <!-- Modal -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal<?= $index ?>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">x</button>
                                    <div class="slider-popup">
                                        <?php
                                        foreach ($row['slider-popup-tehn'] as $imageIndex => $imageRow) {
                                        ?>
                                            <div class="slider-popup-item">
                                                <img src="<?= $imageRow['slider-popup-tehn-picture'] ?>" alt="docs">
                                            </div>
                                        <?php
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <h3 class="portfolio-box-title">
                                <?= $row['name-portfolio'] ?>
                            </h3>

                            <p class="portfolio-box-address">
                                <?= $row['desc-portfolio'] ?>
                            </p>
                            
                            <button class="portfolio-p" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal<?= $index ?>">
                                подробнее
                                <svg width="9" height="18" viewBox="0 0 9 18" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="M1.6428 1L7.7428 9.21622L1.6428 17" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2"/>
                                </svg>

                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
```